# How to solve action client not connected?

Tags: ros, gazebo

Does anyone know how to solve error `action client not connected`?

The error text is:

```
[ WARN] [1559064181.400017201, 235.919000000]: Waiting for arm_controller_moveit/joint_trajectory_action to come up
[ WARN] [1559064188.755204272, 241.920000000]: Waiting for arm_controller_moveit/joint_trajectory_action to come up
[ERROR] [1559064196.377289892, 247.920000000]: Action client not connected: arm_controller_moveit/joint_trajectory_action
```

When I try to see all action servers with the command:

```
rostopic list | grep -i goal
```

This is output:

```
 /execute_trajectory/goal  
 /joint_trajectory_action/goal
 /move_base_simple/goal  
 /move_group/goal  
 /pickup/goal  
 /place/goal
```

I am using `joint_trajectory_action` action server, but I tried with other and it is not working.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

You have a namespace mismatch. Your ros node is looking for the action server at:

```
/arm_controller_moveit/joint_trajectory_action
```

but your setup is actually running it at:

```
/joint_trajectory_action
```

This bug report https://github.com/ros-planning/moveit/issues/1263 fixed it by changing their controllers.yaml file to:

```
name: joint_trajectory_action
action_ns: ''
```